# MASTER-MASTER repliation

Tags: mysql-5.6, linux

MySql in master A ceate user after using replicate-do-db filter on Master A, that user is not showing on Master B by this query-------select User from mysql.user; how to completely access both machines .... (linux redhat6)

Answer (score 0):

`replicate-do` says to replicate that table *but nothing else*.  That is, the "grant" tables are won't be replicated".

How did you "create the user"?  `CREATE USER`?  `GRANT`?  Manipulate mysql.user?  Something else.

Did you do `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`?